# nginx+wordpress permission denied and undefined function

Tags: wordpress, nginx, config

I'm trying to get wordpress running in a subdirectory of an existing nginx (v1.14) server. The rest of the server works fine. I've copied the relevant lines of my nginx.conf below. If I remove the lines that refer directly to the wordpress (wp) directory, then I get an error complaining that wp has called an undefined function "mysql_connect". When I leave the lines that directly refer to the wp directory, it complains about permission denied.

I've looked through a bunch of other posts about this but I can't seem to find any solutions that solve the issue for me. I've tried:

1. adding `define( 'WP_USE_EXT_MYSQL', true );` to wp-config.php and toggling the boolean
2. adding / removing $uri/ from nginx.conf
3. chmodding the wordpress dir and contents (755 for the dir and 644 for the contents)
4. adding / removing index.php to the wordpress location definition in nginx.conf

I have no idea how to troubleshoot this any further.

```
...

http {
  ...
  upstream php {
    server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
    server 127.0.0.9000;
  }
  ...
  server_name domain.tld
  root /some/dir
  location / {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
  }
  ...
  location /wordpress {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args;
  }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wordpress)(/.*)$;
  }
  ...
```

Comment: If it's a permission problem, did you check who is the owner of the subdir, is it the same user that run nginx ?

Comment: Why do you need `fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/wordpress)(/.*)$;`?

Comment: @ThaiDuongTran, yes, that's why I ran chmod 755 on the dir and 644 on its contents.

Comment: @RichardSmith I'm not sure, I've tried both including and not including that line. I got it from nginx's site (https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/)